# ¿Es posible cambiar la zona horaria de Laravel dinámicamente?

Tags: laravel

Deseo que los usuarios según su país de origen guarden en la base de datos la información en su horario local, en `config/app` en la opción `timezone` puedo colocar una zona horaria, pero no sé como hacer como hacer para sustituir su valor con una variable.

---

Actualización de la pregunta, lo que hice por la solución que me aporta porloscerros:

```php
public function index()
{
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://www.geoplugin.net/json.gp?ip=".$ip), true);

    $user_timezone = $data['geoplugin_timezone'];

    config(['app.timezone' => $user_timezone]);

    return view('home');
}
```

Pero no lo hice bien, no me funcionó

Comment: as intentado con javascript? dado que este obtiene la zona horaria de donde se ejecuta por lo que se la puedes pasar a php para configurarla.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sí, con el helper [config()](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/helpers#method-config) puedes establecer variables de configuración en tiempo de ejecución pasando un array de pares clave/valor. Sin embargo, ten en cuenta que esta función solo afecta el valor de configuración del request actual y no actualiza sus valores de configuración reales.
Para el timezone sería así:

```php
$user_timezone = 'Asia/Seoul';
config(['app.timezone' => $user_timezone]);
```

Comment: ¡Perfecto gracias!, si una vez que entre el usuario a la Web, obtengo la ubicación según la IP y la guardo en una sesión, podría mantener todas sus actividades con su `timezone` mientras esté la sesión abierta, correcto?

Comment: No sé si te entiendo bien a que te refieres con *sesión*. En el caso mas simple,  el request actual se refiere a que llega una petición (request), se la procesa (realmente empieza en el index.php, pero para nosotros tipicamente en una ruta, controlador, middlewares, etc), y finalmente se retorna una respuesta (una vista, un redirect, un json etc). El ciclo del request está explicado mas detalladamente en la documentación [Request Lifecycle](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/lifecycle). No sé si a eso te refieres...

Comment: En fin, el valor que le asignes se va a mantener hasta que hagas un return view, return redirect, return json, etc... hasta que devuelvas un [REsponse](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/responses) al cliente (al navegador, aplicacion movil, postman, o lo que sea el cliente que hace la petición) @Joe

Comment: Actualicé la pregunta, no lo hice con un response sino obteniendo el valor desde una API

Comment: Solo como dato, los datos de tipo datetime deberían guardarse todos con el mismo timezone, y luego cada usuario convertir los datos a su timezone  particular. Sino, cuando ese usuario cambie su timezone,  los datos en bbdd estarán guardados con el timezone  anterior y ya no serán validos

Comment: Perfecto, muchas gracias!, tendría que guardarlos en UTC y luego según el timezone del usuario hacer el cálculo

Comment: Buen punto @Jakala. Entonces Joe, no se si te sirva esto, aunque tecnicamente responda la pregunta, la pregunta misma pasaría a ser un problema XY (por cierto, editaste la respuesta, no tu pregunta)

Comment: @Joe viendo la actualización en tu pregunta, dices que no te funcionó, pero ahí cambias el timezone y luego no lo usas. Si retornas `return config('app.timezone')` en vez de `return view('home');` ¿te devuelve el timezone hardcodeado en la configuración o el que obtuviste de la api? Por otro lado, si vas a seguir el buen consejo de Jakala, sería mejor que replantees la pregunta

Comment: @porloscerros no esperaba la sugerencia de `jakala` pero me puede servir, de igual manera quiero intentar tu consejo

Comment: Sí, disculpa, actualicé la respuesta

Answer (score 1):

te puede funcionar algo tan simple como pedirselo al mismo usuario y pasarlo al servidor ejemplo:

```js
timezone = Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone;
console.log(timezone);
```